# Strang behavior of selected tag on IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, selected

Can anyone explain for me that when I use Japanese character in the first option of select tag, there is an empty space at the end of option ? 
Was this a bug ? or This is a style of browser (IE 11,Edge)

[image: Strange behavior of selected tag on IE 11,Edge]

This also have strange when selected have no value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide relevant HTML and CSS plus possible frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

I test the issue with IE 11, MS Edge 42 and MS Edge Chromium browser.

In my test, I noticed that IE 11 and MS Edge Chromium browser do not display the extra space but MS Edge(legacy) 42 browser displayed some space.

Test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>


<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">ボルボ</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Output in MS Edge Chromium browser:

[image]

Output in MS Edge(legacy) 42 browser:

[image]

I tried to search for the issue and found that this space is added by the browsing engine. This is not a bug. You can try to apply the CSS may help to get the desired appearance of control.

Reference:

[Styling Japanese text across browsers and platforms](http://www.nobadmemories.com/blog/2017/04/better-together-displaying-japanese-and-english-text-on-the-web/)